# How to read a function value from a class?

Tags: class, trading, mql5

How to read a value of the function **`CheckPatternAllBullish()`** in a class  **`CCandlePattern`** ?

I want to read it inside the `void OnTick(){...}`

```
// Print( fican.CheckPatternAllBullish() );
```

> Error: invalid pointer access in 'candlepatterns.mqh' (60,64)

Line 60 is:

```
double   Open(int ind)    const { return(m_open.GetData(ind));
```

The code is:

```
#include <Expert\Expert.mqh>
#include <candlepatterns.mqh>

ulong                    Expert_MagicNumber        =3434;        // 
bool                     Expert_EveryTick          =false;       // 

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Global expert object                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
CExpert ExtExpert;
CCandlePattern fican;
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Initialization function of the expert                            |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit(){
   if(!ExtExpert.Init(Symbol(),Period(),Expert_EveryTick,Expert_MagicNumber)) {//--- failed
      printf(__FUNCTION__+": error initializing expert");   ExtExpert.Deinit();   return(INIT_FAILED);  }

//--- Creating signal
   CExpertSignal *signal = new CExpertSignal;
   if(signal==NULL){                printf(__FUNCTION__+": error creating signal"); ExtExpert.Deinit();   return(INIT_FAILED);  }
   ExtExpert.InitSignal(signal);

   //CIndicators *indicators = new  CIndicators;
   //if(indicators==NULL){                printf(__FUNCTION__+": IND NIJE dignut signal"); ExtExpert.Deinit();   return(INIT_FAILED);  }
   //ExtExpert.InitIndicators(indicators);

   //--- Creating filter CMySignalEnvelopes
   //CMySignalEnvelopes *filter0=new CMySignalEnvelopes;
   CCandlePattern *filter0 = new CCandlePattern;      
   if(filter0==NULL){               printf(__FUNCTION__+": error creating filter0");  ExtExpert.Deinit();  return(INIT_FAILED); }


   filter0.InitSignal(signal);
   filter0.InitIndicators();
   filter0.MAPeriod(22);
   filter0.ValidationSettings();

   signal.AddFilter(filter0);   //--- Set filter parameters

  //--- Tuning of all necessary indicators
  if(!ExtExpert.InitIndicators()){  printf(__FUNCTION__+": error initializing indicators"); ExtExpert.Deinit();  return(INIT_FAILED); }

   //if(!filter0.InitIndicators(indicators)){  printf(__FUNCTION__+": error initializing CC "); ExtExpert.Deinit();  return(INIT_FAILED); }
   //filter0.ValidationSettings();
   //filter0.InitSignal(signal);



   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| "Tick" event handler function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick(){
   ExtExpert.OnTick();
   //fican.InitIndicators();
   //fican.CheckPatternAllBullish();
   //Print(fican.CheckPatternAllBullish());
   Print("Read price "+ExtExpert.Low(0)+" O1 "+ExtExpert.Open(1)+" C1 "+ExtExpert.Close(1)+" O2 "+ExtExpert.Open(2));
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Deinitialization function of the expert                          |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason){
   ExtExpert.Deinit();
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| "Trade" event handler function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTrade(){
   ExtExpert.OnTrade();
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| "Timer" event handler function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTimer(){
   ExtExpert.OnTimer();
}
```

File **`candlepatterns.mqh`** :

```
  #include <Expert\ExpertSignal.mqh>
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| enumerators                                                      |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    enum ENUM_CANDLE_PATTERNS  // candlestick patterns
      {
       CANDLE_PATTERN_THREE_BLACK_CROWS     = 1,
       CANDLE_PATTERN_THREE_WHITE_SOLDIERS  = 2,
       CANDLE_PATTERN_DARK_CLOUD_COVER      = 3,
       CANDLE_PATTERN_PIERCING_LINE         = 4,
       CANDLE_PATTERN_MORNING_DOJI          = 5,
       CANDLE_PATTERN_EVENING_DOJI          = 6,
       CANDLE_PATTERN_BEARISH_ENGULFING     = 7,
       CANDLE_PATTERN_BULLISH_ENGULFING     = 8,
       CANDLE_PATTERN_EVENING_STAR          = 9,
       CANDLE_PATTERN_MORNING_STAR          = 10,
       CANDLE_PATTERN_HAMMER                = 11,
       CANDLE_PATTERN_HANGING_MAN           = 12,
       CANDLE_PATTERN_BEARISH_HARAMI        = 13,
       CANDLE_PATTERN_BULLISH_HARAMI        = 14,
       CANDLE_PATTERN_BEARISH_MEETING_LINES = 15,
       CANDLE_PATTERN_BULLISH_MEETING_LINES = 16
      };
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| CCandlePattern class.                                            |
    //| Derived from CExpertSignal class.                                |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    class CCandlePattern : public CExpertSignal
      {
    protected:
       //--- indicators
       CiMA              m_MA;
       //--- input parameters
       int               m_ma_period;
       CExpertSignal    *m_signal;         // storing the pointer to the main signal
    public:
       //--- class constructor
                         CCandlePattern();
       //--- input parameters initialization methods
       void              MAPeriod(int period) { m_ma_period=period;                 }
       //--- initialization
       virtual bool      ValidationSettings();
       virtual bool      InitIndicators(CIndicators *indicators);

       //--- method of setting the pointer to the main signal
       virtual bool      InitSignal(CExpertSignal *signal=NULL);

       //--- method for checking of a certiain candlestick pattern
       bool              CheckCandlestickPattern(ENUM_CANDLE_PATTERNS CandlePattern);
       //--- methods for checking of bullish/bearish candlestick pattern
       bool              CheckPatternAllBullish();
       bool              CheckPatternAllBearish();

    protected:
       //--- indicators initialization methods
       bool              InitMA(CIndicators *indicators);
       //--- methods, used for check of the candlestick pattern formation
       double            AvgBody(int ind);
       double            MA(int ind)                const { return(m_MA.Main(ind));             }
       double            Open(int ind)              const { return(m_open.GetData(ind));        }
       double            High(int ind)              const { return(m_high.GetData(ind));        }
       double            Low(int ind)               const { return(m_low.GetData(ind));         }
       double            Close(int ind)             const { return(m_close.GetData(ind));       }
       double            CloseAvg(int ind)          const { return(MA(ind));                    }
       double            MidPoint(int ind)          const { return(0.5*(High(ind)+Low(ind)));   }
       double            MidOpenClose(int ind)      const { return(0.5*(Open(ind)+Close(ind))); }
       //--- methods for checking of candlestick patterns
       bool              CheckPatternThreeBlackCrows();
       bool              CheckPatternThreeWhiteSoldiers();
       bool              CheckPatternDarkCloudCover();
       bool              CheckPatternPiercingLine();
       bool              CheckPatternMorningDoji();
       bool              CheckPatternEveningDoji();
       bool              CheckPatternBearishEngulfing();
       bool              CheckPatternBullishEngulfing();
       bool              CheckPatternEveningStar();
       bool              CheckPatternMorningStar();
       bool              CheckPatternHammer();
       bool              CheckPatternHangingMan();
       bool              CheckPatternBearishHarami();
       bool              CheckPatternBullishHarami();
       bool              CheckPatternBearishMeetingLines();
       bool              CheckPatternBullishMeetingLines();
      };
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| CCandlePattern class constructor.                                |
    //| INPUT:  no.                                                      |
    //| OUTPUT: no.                                                      |
    //| REMARK: no.                                                      |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    void CCandlePattern::CCandlePattern(){
    //--- initialization of protected data
       m_used_series=USE_SERIES_OPEN+USE_SERIES_HIGH+USE_SERIES_LOW+USE_SERIES_CLOSE;
    //--- set default inputs
       m_ma_period=12;
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Validation settings.                                             |
    //| INPUT:  no.                                                      |
    //| OUTPUT: true-if settings are correct, false otherwise.           |
    //| REMARK: no.                                                      |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::ValidationSettings(){
    //--- validation settings of additional filters
       if(!CExpertSignal::ValidationSettings()) return(false);
    //--- initial data checks
       if(m_ma_period<=0)
         {
          printf(__FUNCTION__+": period MA must be greater than 0");
          return(false);
         }
    //--- ok
       return(true);
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Create MA, Open, High, Low and Close time series                 |
    //| INPUT:  indicators -pointer of indicator collection.             |
    //| OUTPUT: true-if successful, false otherwise.                     |
    //| REMARK: no.                                                      |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::InitIndicators(CIndicators *indicators)
      {
    //--- check collection
       if(indicators==NULL) return(false);
    //--- create and initialize MA indicator
       if(!InitMA(indicators)) return(false);
    //--- create and initialize Open series
       if(!InitOpen(indicators)) return(false);
    //--- create and initialize High series
       if(!InitHigh(indicators)) return(false);
    //--- create and initialize Low series
       if(!InitLow(indicators)) return(false);
    //--- create and initialize Close series
       if(!InitClose(indicators)) return(false);
    //--- ok
       return(true);
      }


    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Create MA indicators.                                            |
    //| INPUT:  indicators -pointer of indicator collection.             |
    //| OUTPUT: true-if successful, false otherwise.                     |
    //| REMARK: no.                                                      |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::InitMA(CIndicators *indicators)
      {
    //--- add MA indicator to collection
       if(!indicators.Add(GetPointer(m_MA)))
         {
          printf(__FUNCTION__+": error adding object");
          return(false);
         }
    //--- initialize MA indicator
       if(!m_MA.Create(m_symbol.Name(),m_period,m_ma_period,0,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE))
         {
          printf(__FUNCTION__+": error initializing object");
          return(false);
         }
    //--- resize MA buffer
       m_MA.BufferResize(50);
    //--- ok
       return(true);
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Returns the averaged value of candle body size                   |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    double CCandlePattern::AvgBody(int ind){
       double candle_body=0;
    ///--- calculate the averaged size of the candle's body
       for(int i=ind; i<ind+m_ma_period; i++){
          candle_body+=MathAbs(Open(i)-Close(i));
       }
       candle_body=candle_body/m_ma_period;
    ///--- return body size
       return(candle_body);
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Checks formation of bullish patterns                             |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::CheckPatternAllBullish(){
      Print("Tuka sam "+Open(1));
      return true ;
       return(CheckPatternThreeWhiteSoldiers() || 
              CheckPatternPiercingLine() || 
              CheckPatternMorningDoji() || 
              CheckPatternBullishEngulfing() || 
              CheckPatternBullishHarami() || 
              CheckPatternMorningStar() || 
              CheckPatternBullishMeetingLines());
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Checks formation of bearish patterns                             |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::CheckPatternAllBearish(){
       return(CheckPatternThreeBlackCrows() || 
              CheckPatternDarkCloudCover() || 
              CheckPatternEveningDoji() || 
              CheckPatternBearishEngulfing() || 
              CheckPatternBearishHarami() || 
              CheckPatternEveningStar() || 
              CheckPatternBearishMeetingLines());
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Checks formation of Three Black Crows candlestick pattern        |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::CheckPatternThreeBlackCrows()
      {
    //--- 3 Black Crows
       if((Open(3)-Close(3)>AvgBody(1)) && // long black
          (Open(2)-Close(2)>AvgBody(1)) && 
          (Open(1)-Close(1)>AvgBody(1)) && 
          (MidPoint(2)<MidPoint(3))     && // lower midpoints
          (MidPoint(1)<MidPoint(2)))
          return(true);
    //---
       return(false);
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Checks formation of Three White Soldiers candlestick pattern     |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::CheckPatternThreeWhiteSoldiers()
      {
    //--- 3 White Soldiers
       if((Close(3)-Open(3)>AvgBody(1)) && // long white
          (Close(2)-Open(2)>AvgBody(1)) && 
          (Close(1)-Open(1)>AvgBody(1)) && 
          (MidPoint(2)>MidPoint(3))     && // higher midpoints
          (MidPoint(1)>MidPoint(2)))
          return(true);
    //---
       return(false);
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Checks formation of Dark Cloud Cover candlestick pattern         |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::CheckPatternDarkCloudCover()
      {
    //--- Dark cloud cover
       if((Close(2)-Open(2)>AvgBody(1)) && // long white
          (Close(1)<Close(2))           && // close within previous body
          (Close(1)>Open(2))            && 
          (MidOpenClose(2)>CloseAvg(1)) && // uptrend
          (Open(1)>High(2)))               // open at new high  
          return(true);
    //---
       return(false);
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Checks formation of Piercing Line candlestick pattern            |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::CheckPatternPiercingLine()
      {
    //--- Piercing Line
       if((Close(1)-Open(1)>AvgBody(1)) && // long white
          (Open(2)-Close(2)>AvgBody(1)) && // long black
          (Close(2)>Close(1))           && // close inside previous body
          (Close(1)<Open(2))            && 
          (MidOpenClose(2)<CloseAvg(2)) && // downtrend
          (Open(1)<Low(2)))                // close inside previous body
          return(true);
    //---
       return(false);
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Checks formation of Morning Doji candlestick pattern             |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::CheckPatternMorningDoji()
      {
    //--- Morning Doji
       if((Open(3)-Close(3)>AvgBody(1)) &&
          (AvgBody(2)<AvgBody(1)*0.1)   &&
          (Close(2)<Close(3))           &&
          (Open(2)<Open(3))             &&
          (Open(1)>Close(2))            &&
          (Close(1)>Close(2)))
          return(true);
    //---
       return(false);
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Checks formation of Evening Doji candlestick pattern             |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::CheckPatternEveningDoji()
      {
    //--- Evening Doji
       if((Close(3)-Open(3)>AvgBody(1)) &&
          (AvgBody(2)<AvgBody(1)*0.1)   &&
          (Close(2)>Close(3))           &&
          (Open(2)>Open(3))             &&
          (Open(1)<Close(2))            &&
          (Close(1)<Close(2)))
          return(true);
    //---
       return(false);
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Checks formation of Bearish Engulfing candlestick pattern        |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::CheckPatternBearishEngulfing()
      {
    //--- Bearish Engulfing
       if((Open(2)<Close(2))            &&
          (Open(1)-Close(1)>AvgBody(1)) &&
          (Close(1)<Open(2))            &&
          (MidOpenClose(2)>CloseAvg(2)) &&
          (Open(1)>Close(2)))
          return(true);
    //---
       return(false);
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Checks formation of Bullish Engulfing candlestick pattern        |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::CheckPatternBullishEngulfing()
      {
    //--- Bullish Engulfing
       if((Open(2)>Close(2))            &&
          (Close(1)-Open(1)>AvgBody(1)) && 
          (Close(1)>Open(2))            &&
          (MidOpenClose(2)<CloseAvg(2)) && 
          (Open(1)<Close(2)))
          return(true);
    //---
       return(false);
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Checks formation of Evening Star candlestick pattern             |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::CheckPatternEveningStar()
      {
    //--- Evening Star
       if((Close(3)-Open(3)>AvgBody(1))              && 
          (MathAbs(Close(2)-Open(2))<AvgBody(1)*0.5) && 
          (Close(2)>Close(3))                        &&
          (Open(2)>Open(3))                          &&
          (Close(1)<MidOpenClose(3)))
          return(true);
    //---
       return(false);
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Checks formation of Morning Star candlestick pattern             |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::CheckPatternMorningStar()
      {
    //--- Morning Star
       if((Open(3)-Close(3)>AvgBody(1))              &&
          (MathAbs(Close(2)-Open(2))<AvgBody(1)*0.5) &&
          (Close(2)<Close(3))                        &&
          (Open(2)<Open(3))                          &&
          (Close(1)>MidOpenClose(3)))
          return(true);
    //---
       return(false);
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Checks formation of Hammer candlestick pattern                   |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::CheckPatternHammer()
      {
    //--- Hammer
       if((MidPoint(1)<CloseAvg(2))                                  && // down trend
          (MathMin(Open(1),Close(1))>(High(1)-(High(1)-Low(1))/3.0)) && // body in upper 1/3
          (Close(1)<Close(2)) && (Open(1)<Open(2)))                     // body gap
          return(true);
    //---
       return(false);
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Checks formation of Hanging Man candlestick pattern              |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::CheckPatternHangingMan()
      {
    //--- Hanging man
       if((MidPoint(1)>CloseAvg(2))                                 && // up trend
          (MathMin(Open(1),Close(1)>(High(1)-(High(1)-Low(1))/3.0)) && // body in upper 1/3
          (Close(1)>Close(2)) && (Open(1)>Open(2))))                   // body gap
          return(true);
    //---
       return(false);
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Checks formation of Bearish Harami candlestick pattern           |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::CheckPatternBearishHarami()
      {
    //--- Bearish Harami
       if((Close(1)<Open(1))              && // black day
          ((Close(2)-Open(2))>AvgBody(1)) && // long white
          ((Close(1)>Open(2))             && 
          (Open(1)<Close(2)))             && // engulfment
          (MidPoint(2)>CloseAvg(2)))         // up trend
          return(true);
    //---
       return(false);
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Checks formation of Bullish Harami candlestick pattern           |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::CheckPatternBullishHarami()
      {
    //--- Bullish Harami
       if((Close(1)>Open(1))              && // white day
          ((Open(2)-Close(2))>AvgBody(1)) && // long black
          ((Close(1)<Open(2))             && 
          (Open(1)>Close(2)))             && // engulfment
          (MidPoint(2)<CloseAvg(2)))         // down trend
          return(true);
    //---
       return(false);
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Checks formation of Bearish Meeting Lines candlestick pattern    |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::CheckPatternBearishMeetingLines()
      {
    //--- Bearish MeetingLines
       if((Close(2)-Open(2)>AvgBody(1))                && // long white
          ((Open(1)-Close(1))>AvgBody(1))              && // long black
          (MathAbs(Close(1)-Close(2))<0.1*AvgBody(1)))    // doji close
          return(true);
    //---
       return(false);
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Checks formation of Bullish Meeting Lines candlestick pattern    |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::CheckPatternBullishMeetingLines()
      {
    //--- Bullish MeetingLines
       if((Open(2)-Close(2)>AvgBody(1))             && // long black
          ((Close(1)-Open(1))>AvgBody(1))           && // long white
          (MathAbs(Close(1)-Close(2))<0.1*AvgBody(1))) // doji close
          return(true);
    //---
       return(false);
      }

      //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Initialization signal object                                     |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::InitSignal(CExpertSignal *signal){
       m_signal=signal;
       return(true);
      }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| Checks formation of a certain candlestick pattern                |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    bool CCandlePattern::CheckCandlestickPattern(ENUM_CANDLE_PATTERNS CandlePattern)
      {
       switch(CandlePattern)
         {
          case CANDLE_PATTERN_THREE_BLACK_CROWS:      return(CheckPatternThreeBlackCrows());
          case CANDLE_PATTERN_THREE_WHITE_SOLDIERS:   return(CheckPatternThreeWhiteSoldiers());
          case CANDLE_PATTERN_DARK_CLOUD_COVER:       return(CheckPatternDarkCloudCover());
          case CANDLE_PATTERN_PIERCING_LINE:          return(CheckPatternPiercingLine());
          case CANDLE_PATTERN_MORNING_DOJI:           return(CheckPatternMorningDoji());
          case CANDLE_PATTERN_EVENING_DOJI:           return(CheckPatternEveningDoji());
          case CANDLE_PATTERN_BEARISH_ENGULFING:      return(CheckPatternBearishEngulfing());
          case CANDLE_PATTERN_BULLISH_ENGULFING:      return(CheckPatternBullishEngulfing());
          case CANDLE_PATTERN_EVENING_STAR:           return(CheckPatternEveningStar());
          case CANDLE_PATTERN_MORNING_STAR:           return(CheckPatternMorningStar());
          case CANDLE_PATTERN_HAMMER:                 return(CheckPatternHammer());
          case CANDLE_PATTERN_HANGING_MAN:            return(CheckPatternHangingMan());
          case CANDLE_PATTERN_BEARISH_HARAMI:         return(CheckPatternBearishHarami());
          case CANDLE_PATTERN_BULLISH_HARAMI:         return(CheckPatternBullishHarami());
          case CANDLE_PATTERN_BEARISH_MEETING_LINES:  return(CheckPatternBearishMeetingLines());
          case CANDLE_PATTERN_BULLISH_MEETING_LINES:  return(CheckPatternBullishMeetingLines());
         }
    //---
       return(false);
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

> Error: invalid pointer access in 'candlepatterns.mqh' (162,20)

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what is line 162 in your `candlespattern.mqh`, you can check it yourself please, it is somewhere near or in the `bool CCandlePattern::InitMA(CIndicators *indicators)` function or maybe above, below - really do not know, if to copy your file into notepad - it shows a blank line is 162. Please indicate that (maybe as a screenshot or just tell function name and the line itself), then let us go further.

If it is in `bool CCandlePattern::InitMA(CIndicators *indicators)` function, then the `OnInit()` function doesnt finish properly I suppose, easiest way to see that - add a line `printf("%i %s - successful",__LINE__,__FUNCTION__);` or just look if EA loaded successfully on the chart, but i think it doesnt and failed somewhere during initialization after you have declared `filter0` so you will need to debug to see which line is passed successfully and which is not (for that, try `if(!filter0.InitSignal(signal)){printf("%i %s - error",__LINE__,__FUNCTION__);/*and expert deinit?*/}` for that line and for the following lines that `filter0` is mentioned if those functions are boolean (probably MQ5 developers made those functions boolean to help detect errors?)

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Error 
invalid pointer access in 'candlepatterns.mqh' (60,64)

Line 60 is
double            Open(int ind)              const { return(m_open.GetData(ind));

Comment: ok and what does `filter0.InitIndicators();' mean? seems you MUST pass `CIndicator *ind` as a reference in that function (line 43)? Next: what about `if(!ExtExpert.InitIndicators())` - same question from the ea file, are you sure you do not need any indicators in it(I mean your CCandlePattern)? if so, then i would try to declare `filter0`, then `signal`, then match them with `signal.AddFilter(filter0)` and finally `ExtExpert.InitSignal(signal);` in `OnInit()`

Comment: In the end i just want to get the result off 
CheckPatternAllBullish()

As i get this 
 Print("Read price "+ExtExpert.Low(0)+" O1 "+ExtExpert.Open(1)+" C1 "+ExtExpert.Close(1)+" O2 "+ExtExpert.Open(2)); 

Can you help me how?

Comment: where you put that line and what you received? you have three questions to analyze and think yourself - `null` is passed into `InitIndicators()`; `Ext.InitIndicators()`(but maybe not so important for now); and rearranging the order to see if it works better

Comment: With and without (ExtExpert.InitIndicators(indicators);)
doing the same.
I want to eliminate everything that is not necessary.
I just want go get this function  CheckPatternAllBullish();

Comment: i think the main problem is with incorrect order - first you initialized indicators then add filter0 - that is described in third part of my answer, inside OnInit()

Comment: Great. Please, upvote/accept when your rating will allow you to do that.